# How to get access_token for a client_id, redirect_uri, code and client secret for Facebook application integration, C#?

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-apps

My facebook integration used to work but for a few days it is not any longer?
As I have read around and found that I need to do a webrequest now to get access_token.
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id={0}&redirect_uri=&client_secret={1}&code={2}
The issue is that I don't receive any response. Have you guys implemented a way how to receive access token?
I use debugger tool from facebook using this request I make and I receive 400 error bad request. 
This is the link:
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=234035623293956&redirect_uri=https://www.hotelopro.com/TestFb.aspx&client_secret=38c373c3f3723d793f58cb745c9b0364&code=efa62750b66f1a2207cafdf6.1-100002637731450|qn9fIozBUHBYuNchC_f4HLXFbiI
If it helps you.
PS: I saw a similar question here [Facebook Access Token from Website cookie using new OAuth and C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7313131/facebook-access-token-from-website-cookie-using-new-oauth-and-c-sharp) but without answer :-?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Do not use** the "official" C# library. The code is outdated and not updated!

Try http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/ (I worked in C #. NET 4 - everything without problems).

Comment: after all i went on facebooksdk solution, I integrated it and it is working fine

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the official facebook c# sdk. The project is here: https://github.com/facebook/csharp-sdk

The facebook release blog is here: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/395/